# Can't connect to remote instance via ssh tunneling + proxying

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, ssh, portforwarding

Having trouble connecting to remote server via ssh tunneling.

I'm not that experienced with ssh or portforwarding. I'm trying to forward traffic from an application on a remote lab server to a port on my laptop so I can monitor the traffic. I can log into the server without a problem using:

```
ssh -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem username@server.com
```

However, when I try to create a tunnel (which I am routing through a proxy server via SwitchyOmega):

```
ssh -L 3128:localhost:8888 -N -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem username@server.com
```

I still can't access the page.

My OS is El Capitan and I'm using Chrome, but the remote server is running ubuntu. I appreciate any advice or suggested reading!

EDIT: Initially thought the server was on AWS with a fixed IP, but it turns out its a physical lab server.

Comment: What ports do you have open on your EC2 SecurityGroup?  Make sure you have the remote port open (in this case 8888).

Comment: Are you allowing ssh from any address (0.0.0.0/0) in your Security Group ?

Comment: @bcampolo yes 8888 is open

Comment: @lafferc yeah security group is allowing for ssh access from any ip

Comment: How are you trying to access the page?

Comment: @Jakuje Currently entering in the IP address of the remote server directly - as mentioned in the edits, I initially thought it was an EC2 instance but it's actually just a remote server.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create the fowarding accessible by others, therefore do not bind `localhost`, but the external IP or `*`. Also you need to specify the `-g` switch, if you are connecting to the forwarded port remotely:

```
ssh -g -L *:3128:localhost:8888 -N -i ~/.ssh/mykey.pem username@server.com
```

Answer (score 1):

In a new terminal window on your local machine, SSH into the remote machine using the following options to setup port forwarding.

```
ssh -N -L 3128:localhost:8888 user@remote_server
```

-N options tells SSH that no commands will be run and it’s useful for port forwarding, and -L lists the port forwarding configuration that we setup.

To close the SSH tunnel simply do ctrl-c.